# Vue Computed property not updating - Strange behavior of undefined data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

For the sake of explanation, i made an example of code in a `.vue` single file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h1>{{score}} : Score with undefined minScore but declared on data</h1>
    <h1>{{score2}} : Score with undeclared/undefined minScore2</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      minScore: undefined,  
      // Uncomment minScore2 to fix weird behavior
      // minScore2: undefined
    }
  },
  computed: {
    score() {
      return this.minScore + 5
    },
     score2() {
       return this.minScore2 + 5
    }
  },
  created() {
   setTimeout(() => { 
     this.minScore = 10
     this.minScore2 = 10
}, 1000)
  }
};
</script>
```

We use the above component to display score as a `computed` property,
calculating it's value by summarizing it with the number 5.
After 1 second we try to update `this.minScore` and `this.minScore2` using the same `setTimeout()` function.

The component loads, the template asks for the computed properties `score` and `score2`.
Both show `NaN` at the beginning. After the 1 second passes, `this.minScore` updates it's value correctly to the number 15, but `this.minScore` **stucks to the previous `NaN`** result.

The only difference is that `minScore` is declared as `undefined` explicitly and `minScore2` is not.
There are not any error messages in console.

**My question is why in Vue you need to implicitly initialize an `undefined` property, when in javaScript both of the properties would be treated as `undefined`?**

P.S. I know that javaScript's outcome from the function `undefined + number === NaN'

You can try it on the following codepen
[Link for Live Codepen](https://codepen.io/abregre/pen/NWvERGq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add root-level reactive properties to an existing component instance: [Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties).

You don't get any error, because the code is valid (you can console.log(this.minScore) and see that the property is set), but the properties that you add to `this` are not reactive and the template update is not triggered.

If you need to not declare the properties upfront, there is a solution. First, make them non-root.

```javascript
data(){
  return {
    unitializedProperties: {
      // here will go new properties. 
    }
  }
}
```

Then use the set() method to add new non-root reactive props.

```javascript
 this.$set(this.unitializedProperties, 'minScore', 10)
```

You can view it in action in your edited [codepen](https://codepen.io/bgtor/pen/bGrQoqo)